# Ubuntu one syncing only folders and no content!

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, sync

I know that anyone could say that this question already exists but my problem still exists. So what do you suggest?

I have a folder in my laptop and i want it to be accessible from my desktop and my other devices.BUT only sub folders are syncing and no content of them.

Thanks, any help would be great!

Comment: Does Ubunte One has access to the files?

Comment: What access?Be more specific please!

Comment: Sorry. Files and folders can't be used through anyone and every application. For more info http://www.zzee.com/solutions/linux-permissions.shtml. Does Ubuntu One has rights to copy the files? If not, you've to set the correct rights to those folders or usergroup.

Comment: How can i determine if ubuntu one has the rights?thanks

Comment: Please tell me how can i give permissions on this folder?Should i change the ownership or something?Could you step by step guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For copying files Ubuntu One needs read access. You've to check if Ubuntu One has that access.

First determine which user and usergroupt runs Ubuntu One by using

```
# ps -C ubuntuone-syncd -o uid,gid
```

On my machine it gave me this result

```
  UID   GID
  1000  1000
```

Get the corresponding name of the GID

```
# id -G
# id -G -n
```

Results will be like this:

```
1000 4 20 24 46 116 118 124 
orangetux adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

You can see that usergroup `orangetux` has group id `1000`

Now check the folder you want to sync

```
# cd /path/to/folder
```

Now get a view of the folder

```
# ls -l
```

Output is something like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 orangetux orangetux   179 2012-03-19 20:04 examples.desktop
```

The line tells me this

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Root has read and write permissions.
Group has read permissions.
Owner has read permissions.

```
orangetux orangetux
```

This line tells me that the owner of the file is `'orangetux'` and the group is `'orangetux'`

Now you know if Ubuntu One has permissions to upload the file.

When group/user is oke, but the group/user has no permission you can change it with this command

```
# sudo chmod 444 .
```

Which gives read access to root, group and user in this directory.

When group/user of Ubuntu One aren't the same as the files, you can add the Ubuntu One user to the usergroup of the file with this command:

```
# useradd -G {group} user
```